# Why do so many circleCI configs use `version: 2` for their workflows?

Tags: circleci

I keep seeing this pattern around, and I haven't been able to figure out *why* people do it. I figure there's some dusty tome somewhere explaining why, or maybe just my google skills are off today, but can anyone tell me *why* so many people have `workflows` at version 2?

e.g. the example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921001733/https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs), excerpt below

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  my-executor:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:jessie
    working_directory: /tmp

jobs:
  flow:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:
      - ...

  downstream:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:
      - ...

workflows:
  version: 2

  btd:
    jobs:
      - flow
      - downstream:
          requires:
            - flow
```

I figure I should probably be cargo-culting this in until I know *why* people do it, but I dislike doing that without any understanding :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workflows `version` field was used to issue warnings for deprecation or breaking changes during v2 Beta, and it is deprecated as of CircleCI v2.1.

2 is the only valid number besides 1